# How to print a zero if the a datframe is empty

Tags: python, pandas

I am counting the number of `True` and `False` conditions. I get an empty output when I count `False`. Is there a way to save the output with zero when the file is empty?

df

```
,name,count,cond
0,a,10,True
1,b,11,True
2,c,12,True
```

tried

```
df = df[df['cond'] == True]
T = int(df['count'].values)
print("T:", T)

df = df[df['cond'] == False]
F = int(df['count'].values)
print("F:", F)
```

Comment: `df['count'].values if not df.empty else 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this:

```
F = int(df['count'].values)
```

by this

```
F = int(df['count'].values) if len(df)>0 else 0
```